# Counting results in periods of time in the day

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Suppose I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE associacao
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  idusuario character varying(50),
  idunit character varying(50),
  dataassociacao timestamp with time zone,
  codigo bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT associacao_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

with data like

```
id | idusuario | idunit | dataassociacao               | codigo
1  | "100000"  | "200"  | "2011-08-25 10:20:25.123-03" |   3
2  | "100000"  | "300"  | "2011-08-25 10:20:25.123-03" |   3
3  | "400000"  | "500"  | "2011-08-25 05:20:26.123-03" |   3
4  | "400000"  | "600"  | "2011-08-25 05:20:26.123-03" |   3
5  | "700000"  | "800"  | "2011-08-25 16:20:26.123-03" |   3
6  | "700000"  | "900"  | "2011-08-25 16:20:26.123-03" |   3
7  | "1000000" | "1100" | "2011-08-25 21:20:26.123-03" |   3
8  | "1200000" | "1300" | "2011-08-24 22:20:23.123-03" |   2
9  | "1200000" | "1300" | "2011-08-24 22:20:26.123-03" |   3
```

I want a SQL Statement that divides the day into 3 shifts (22:00:00.001 through 06:00:00.000, 06:00:00.001 through 14:00:00.000 and 14:00:00.001 through 22:00:00.000) and count how many distinct idusuario's each part has.

so far I have reached the following code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
       WHEN DATE_PART('hour', dataassociacao) BETWEEN 6 AND 14 THEN 1 
       WHEN DATE_PART('hour', dataassociacao) BETWEEN 14 AND 22 THEN 2 
       WHEN DATE_PART('hour', dataassociacao) BETWEEN 22 AND 24 THEN 3 
       WHEN DATE_PART('hour', dataassociacao) BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 3
    END AS data, COUNT(distinct idusuario)
FROM associacao
WHERE codigo = 3
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY data;
```

which gives me the following table (with the above example)

```
data | count(idusuario)
 1   |       1
 2   |       3
 3   |       1
```

my problems are:

1. if I wanted a count by day, I wouldnt get the shifts counted correctly, like, 3rd shift (the night shift) would get counted as if they were working from 00:00:00.001 through 06:00:00.000 and then again from 22:00:00.001 through 00:00:00.000 in the same day, and not from 22:00:00.001 the day before through 06:00:00.000 the current day
2. the date is only comparing hour, this way, every record from 22:00:00.000 through 22:59:59.999 are counting towards 2nd shift, not 3rd shift which is the correct.

Any toughts??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a complete solution, but if the shift actually ends at 21:59:59, then you can use shifts ending at hour 21, and starting at 22.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think it's both more typical and more logical for periods of any kind to *start*, rather than to end, at the very beginning of an hour. Why, we even call it the *beginning* of an hour. And even when it is said that something *ends* at a certain hour, I think that implies a *start* of a period when that something has ceased to be, i.e. it has ended just before the beginning of the hour.

Comment: Actually the shifts time arent exactly at beginning of hour, but 15 minutes after it, I just didnt want to complicate even more my question, and I have the same issues being at 1 ms after the hour or 15 minutes... and btw, that is defined by the costumer, I can't change shifts time due to my systems fault =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is along the lines of what you want...

First, you're going to want a [Calendar File](http://codeinet.blogspot.com/2006/08/auxiliary-calendar-table-for-sql.html), if you don't have one already.

Second, go ahead and define a `Shift` table.  This would probably be important for tracking in any case, and is crucial here.  Quick and dirty definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Shift (Shift INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                    Start_Offset SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                    End_Offset SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                    CONSTRAINT Shift_PK PRIMARY KEY(Shift))
```

Data to insert:

```
INSERT INTO Shift VALUES(1, 6, 14), (2, 14, 22), (3, 22, 30)
```

Then you should be able to run this query:

```
SELECT a.Calendar_Date, b.Shift, COUNT(DISTINCT c.idusuario)
FROM calendar as a
CROSS JOIN Shift as b
JOIN associacao as c
ON c.dataassociacao >= a.Calendar_Date + ((INTERVAL '1 hours') * b.Start_Offset)
AND c.dataassociacao < a.Calendar_Date + ((INTERVAL '1 hours') * b.End_Offset)
GROUP BY a.Calendar_Date, b.Shift
ORDER BY a.Calendar_Date, b.Shift
```

This results in:

```
Calendar_Date    Shift    Count
=======================================
2011-08-24       3        2
2011-08-25       1        1
2011-08-25       2        2
```

(Please note: I performed all build/test work on DB2, which doesn't have the interval functions.  From looking at the documentation and associated information online, the given query *should* be equivalent to what I wrote, but I cannot test on an instance of PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, altough it takes 356134 ms to run it gives me the desired result with associacao being a 7360 row table, now I need to run the same query on a 20000 row one, but well, at least it gives me time to think of a better solution; im running analyzer to see if it can be done faster, again, thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  You could maybe speed it up by having three `union`ed version of the queries (by shift) - not joining to a `Shift` table.  Not well extensible, though.  Also, don't forget to restrict your selection of dates from the calendar file, as that may/will help.  Beyond that... what indices do you have?

Comment: Also, you might consider making some of your columns smaller datatypes -  `codigo` could probably be just a regular `int`, as could (possibly, but I don't know the use case) `idusuario` and `idunit`.  Your `id` column as well, seems overly large.  This won't necessarily speed up your query time, but will likely cut down on the size of your tables (this will of course be subject to your data acquisition needs - if your production table sits around 20000 rows, there's no way you need those datatypes for those columns).

Comment: actually im creating and testing the system yet, so its on early stages, Yes, I intentionally oversized the data types just to be sure, right now my associacao table is with 43k rows, and raising incredibly fast, this tends to slow down once everything is on its place, the idusuario and idunit are character varyng because they can be just numbers or they can be a 12byte hex code and probably the second option will be used mostly. I did restrict the calendar and it took about the same 6 minutes but for 34k rows on associacao, I wont be running this query a lot so for now its acceptable time.

Comment: I dont want to leave any intelligence on the database, because I will not always use my own db for this solution.